How to pass data to the OrderAggregate
I am working on an application created using the Domain Driven Design approach. I have an Order aggregate, which consists of OrderItems and the TotalPrice.
The order price is calculated by multiplying the quantity and price of each item. To get the total amount, I call GetTotalAmount() from the aggregate.
Now, here’s where things get tricky: I need to calculate a discount based on the amount spent in the last 31 days.
How should I pass this information to the OrderAggregate? Is it acceptable to retrieve the total spent amount in the Application Layer and pass it to a method like GetTotalAmount(decimal discount)? Or should I create a domain service, inject IOrderRepository into it to handle the calculation, and call this Domain Service from the Application Layer?

Before I'd even reached your final paragraph, I was already thinking it needed a domain service.
The Order aggregate should not have any knowledge of previous spend, so it needs to be used in some form of orchestration to perform the use case. A domain service would be the first 'level' at which to consider that orchestration. Whether that's where it's most suitable in the long term isn't clear right now, but it's the right first step in my opinion..

Thank you for your reply @david-osborne
If I create a domain service, it will have only one purpose: calling a repository method.
It might look like this:
public OrderDiscountDomainService()
{
_orderRepository.GetTotalSpentInLast31DaysAsync(order.CustomerId);
}
Don't you think this is an unnecessary abstraction in this case?
Would you call this service in the Application Layer and pass the result to the GetTotalAmount() method, or would you handle it differently?

What about the parts that calculate the discount? Will that be part of the Order aggregate?

Good question. Would you move the logic to a Domain Service?

Potentially. It sounds like that might be the service's responsibility. Do you need to keep track of why the discount was applied? If so, just altering the order's total will not preserve that.

Yeah, I have to save inormation about it.

So could you do something where the service calculates the discount and then records the discount applied to the Order aggregate so that it can be persisted?
